# How to check google -transparency logs to detect malicious ssl certificates of my domain

Tags: certificate-transparency

I would like to use google certificate transparency API to check the malicious SSL certificates(if any) of my domain. I am able to get all the certificates but how do i check whether the certificate is legitimate or not.

I had found this repository(https://github.com/ProtonMail/ct-monitor) but this simply searches certificates and stores it . What is the use of storing these certificates unless we validate the certificates first.

Can any one suggest me how do i get to know the malicious SSL certificates using this google certificate transparency api.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have tried for this?

Comment: i followed the github code , i had shared

Answer (score 0):

Certificate Transparency logs are, as [explained on the CT site](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/what-is-ct):

> simple network services that maintain cryptographically assured,
> publicly auditable, append-only records of certificates. Anyone can
> submit certificates to a log, although certificate authorities will
> likely be the foremost submitters.

The logging of the certificates in this fashion allows for interested parties (e.g. domain owners) to monitor these logs for malicious/erroneous
entries.

But a certificate being logged in a CT log doesn't mean it isn't a bad certificate. As explained on the CT site:

> Certificate Transparency **relies on existing mitigation mechanisms** to
> address harmful certificates and CAs--for example, certificate
> revocation--the shortened detection time will speed up the overall
> mitigation process when harmful certificates or CAs are discovered.

So CT API won't help you in working out whether a certificate is malicious - you need to check using other methods such as checking of certificate revocation lists (CRLs) or by using the Online Certificate Status Protocol ([OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol)). See this related [question on how to check certs](https://serverfault.com/questions/590504/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificates-have-been-revoked). There are sites that allow for checking of certificates e.g. [revocationcheck.com](https://certificate.revocationcheck.com/). Modern browsers seem to be converging on the use of compressed lists of CRLs - [Mozilla's now using CRLite](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/01/09/crlite-part-1-all-web-pki-revocations-compressed/), whilst [Chrome uses CRLSets](https://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/crlsets).

The CT API allows you verify that a certificate has been logged in the CT logs which means that domain owners can monitor them and promptly insert any malicious/erroneous certificates into the relevant CRLs so they won't be used any longer.